# using "services" as route in phalcon framework makes error

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, phalcon

I'm using phalcon version 2.0.6. When I'm using "services" as controller name in my routing rules, and sending request (http://localhost/MySite/services) phalcon changes controller name to "Services" and then can't find the defined route .
It happens just when controller name is "services".
here is my route :

```
return call_user_func(function(){
    $servicesCollection = new Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection;

    $servicesCollection
        ->setPrefix('/Services')
        ->setHandler('\MySite\Api\Controllers\ServicesController')
        ->setLazy(true);

    $servicesCollection->get('/','get');
    return $servicesCollection;
});
```

This is my controller file

```
namespace Mysite\Api\Controllers;

use \Mysite\Api\Exceptions\HttpException;
use \Mysite\Logic\Services\ServicesLogic;
class ServicesController extends RestController
{
    /**
     * @var \Phalcon\Http\Request
     */
    public $request;
    /**
    * @var ServicesLogic
    */
    protected $logic;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request = $this->di->get('request');
        $this->logic = new ServicesLogic();
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->logic->getList();
    }
}
```

Dose anybody know what's wrong ?

Comment: Provide please Controller

Comment: You can use as example phalcon-rest: Routing https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest/blob/develop/routes/collections/example.php and Controller https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest/blob/develop/controllers/ExampleController.php

Comment: @klay The problem is not about how to routing rules. It's about an exception in routing. When I use the specific world "services" in URI to route request to specific controller it causes problem. it changes the URI and tries to route to a wrong destination. it make some changes like this : 
http://localhost/phalcon/services
will change to 
http://localhost/phalcon/Services